# Using ChangeInterceptor to inspect "Relationship" changes/mutations between entities

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any way to see how the relationships of an Entity were affected/changed inside of a ChangeInterceptor()?  Here is an example using NorthWind Database, when you delete/remove an Order Entity from an Employee Entity where the relationship is one-to-many, one Employee has many Orders, how can detect an Order was removed from the Employee Entity.  I know using the ObjectStateEntry class you can call GetModifiedProperties() to see what Properties changed, but how do we see what Collections/Associations changed?.  Does it have something to do with the RelationshipManager?

```
[ChangeInterceptor("Employees"]
public void OnChangeEmployees(Employee employee, UpdateOperations operations)
{
    //I'm using EntityFramework 4.1
    //We have to dropdown the ObjectContext to detect IA, Independant Association, changes
    ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.CurrentDataSource).ObjectContext;

    ObjectStateEntry entry = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(employee);

    //What do I do here for detecting relationship changes.. I.E and Order was added?


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ChangeInterceptor... Just implement the SavingChanges event handler on the ObjectContext.  This [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5e51e598-88ff-417e-9689-1fb270125ed8) explains how to see if an Entity's relationship was affected.